# What is the volatility of mutual information?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, volatility

For Gaussian data, it is known that the standard deviation or volatility of entropy, $H(X)$ is

$$\sigma_H = \frac{\exp^{H-1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$

I'm not sure how the above is derived, but could someone give a derivation of the volatility of mutual information, $I(X,Y)$?

$$I(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)$$